# Accessing forms from different locations in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, global

Still getting used to WPF from a win forms programmer. I have multiple forms in an application that can be accessed from multiple locations, so I need to keep the forms "global" as I'm not sure of a better terminology.

For instance "Details" can be opened from a "Main Menu" but can also be opened from a grid in "Search", I'd like the details returned from the search to be displayed in the "Details" page even if it was pre-opened from the main menu.

I've come across `Application.Current.Properties` and have started storing a few forms in it but it just feels plain wrong to set:

```
Vehicle vehicleForm = new Vehicle();
Application.Current.Properties["frmVehicle"] = vehicleForm;
```

And then to access it:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties["frmVehicle"] == null)
            Application.Current.Properties["frmVehicle"] = new frmVehicle();

Vehicle vehicleFrm = (Vehicle)Application.Current.Properties["frmVehicle"];
vehicleFrm.Show();
vehicleFrm.Activate();
```

I have just discovered `Application.Current.Windows` as well which has thrown me a little.

What is the most efficient/industry standard way of dealing with form like this?

Comment: What is your question exactly?  There really isn't a big different between WPF Window and a Windows Form.  You would open your child window(s) in similar fashion to opening a windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just check whether [`Application.Current.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) contains an instance of your window. If so then you give it focus, if not then you create an instance.

Comment: I think this is the most logical way of doing it. I had only just learnt about Application.Current.Windows when I posted. What would be the common property to check for when finding out of the window is open in the loop?

Comment: @Oli: There's no need for such a check. Only the opened windows will be in this collection. Make sure to read the remarks on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx

Comment: Thanks Marc, such a simple thing but it's normally things like this I seem to get caught up on. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand how are you opening the window correctly. But if all you want to do is to have one instance of the window through the whole run time of the application, you can use [the Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Basically, the window class has a static property that holds the only instance.

If you don't need to keep any state in the window, you can just create new instance of it every time you want to show it.

Comment: Be careful with using singleton for this. You'd have to block closing the form and make it invisible or so and you certainly don't want to dispose it.

Comment: Now I said 'form' rather than 'window'... damn WPF :-)